# Moving the body of my page closer to the header?

Tags: html, css, position, navbar

I am fairly new to html/css and I am building a page through tumblr. It already had a template which I have changed and added a few extra elements.

I am stuck as I have no idea where to find the code which moves the body of the page up and so there is a significant gap between the navbar and body of page.

what code would i need?
my webpage: http://goldlazerblog.tumblr.com/

Here is my css for my positioning of my title and nav bar. They are in their right place and the only thing I was thinking was to make my main title larger (image file) ??

```
.main-title {
margin: 0 
auto;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
text-align:center;
top: 0;
}

.main-title li {
display: inline;
padding: 10px;
}
.main-title a {
display:inline-block;
padding: 0px;

} 

.nav-bar {
border:NONE solid: NONE;
border-width:1px 0;
list-style:none;
margin: 0px;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
color: #5a5a5a;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: normal;
}
.nav-bar li {
display: inline;
padding:0px;
margin: 0px;
}

.nav-bar a {
display:inline-block;
padding: 15px;

}
```

Comment: You have `header` div which will take space between the navbar and body of page.

Answer (score 0):

```
.content {
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

This should reduce the empty space

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty div with the id of header in there. Perhaps you could set that to display: none if you cannot remove that div.

```
#header.none-header {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a h1 with nothing in it that is taking up your space.

```
<div class="blog-title">
   <h1><a href="/"></a></h1>
</div>
```

You could also remove or hide the parent.

```
<div id="header" class="none-header none-navigation">
```